# Creating a user input list in python

Tags: python, list, input

I'm new to python and I made this code to get a number from the user. Im not sure how but i want to make input boxes equal equal to the number placed in the first line of code.

*code*

```
x = input("How many video games do you own: ")
list1 =[x]

for games in list1:
    name1=input("Enter game1: ")
```

*What i want to happen*

```
How many video games do you own: 4
Video game 1 = 1
Video game 2 = 2
Video game 3 = 3
video Game 4 = 5

[1,2,3,4]
```

no errors, just prints game1

How can i make this happen?

Comment: You should be reading a tutorial or textbook for these basic-python operations, not asking a question immediately on StackOverflow. This isn't a tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

is

```
x = input("How many video games do you own: ")
list1 = []

for games in range(int(x)):
    name1 = input("Enter game1: ")
    list1.append(name1)

print(list1)
```